# Link Does not open in webview?

Tags: android, webview

I am developing an android application , in which i have certain Twits with a specific hash tag like #nokia

i have this link  https://mobile.twitter.com/search/%23nokia should be open in webview without hiding my Tabs at the bottom.How can i do this?
i have already use the method

```
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView  view, String  url)
    {
       // This line we let me load only pages inside Firstdroid Webpage
               if ( url.contains("firstdroid") == true )
                /* Load new URL Don't override URL Link */
                     return false;

       // Return true to override url loading (In this case do nothing).
           return true;
   }
```

any help

Comment: how do you open your webview in your tabhost or tabactivity?

Comment: i have used tabgroupActivity i have to call this link on 4th tab if i open this link in default browser it will work fine but hide my tabs.i have to open without hiding tabs.

Answer (score 2):

When you return true in this method, you should call:

```
view.loadUrl(url);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Olsavage is right. If you want to "override" the URL Loading, you need to return true + call view.loadUrl(url) before you actually return true

Your code should then be:

```
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView  view, String  url)
{
   // This line we let me load only pages inside Firstdroid Webpage
           if ( url.contains("firstdroid") == true )
            /* Load new URL Don't override URL Link */
                 return false;

   // Return true to override url loading (In this case do nothing).
   view.loadUrl(url);
   return true;
}
```

[edit]:

How about the %23 in your URL ? Is that what you want to achieve? Open the actual #hash in the web browser?

Answer (score 0):

in the webview client, instead of the code.

```
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url); // open link in the same web view.
            return true;
        }
    });
```